# SVG: Анимированый градиент под углом?

Tags: анимация, svg, градиент

https://codepen.io/NickNoordijk/pen/VLvxLE?editors=1000#0

```html
<svg width="336px" height="195px">
    <defs>  
     <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" > 
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#000">
       <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#000; #fff; #fff; #000" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff">
       <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#fff; #000; #000; #fff" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </stop>
     </linearGradient> 
    </defs>
      
    <g>
      <path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" d="M315.69646,6.17948262 C328.855897,-3.88648819 332.169516,-0.795739865 323.113707,13.0582738 L217.327474,174.895153 C208.264469,188.760175 193.218185,188.990964 183.71996,175.409636 L126.769111,93.9767151 L12.5417619,181.728698 C-0.593710633,191.81966 -3.91947426,188.74917 5.1230211,174.855879 L110.403975,13.0975513 C119.44219,-0.789163345 134.468377,-1.03753706 143.966601,12.5437917 L200.917445,93.9767151 L315.69646,6.17948262 Z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Это то что у меня есть сейчас, градиент ходит туда сюда, а мне этого не нужно. Нужно чтобы он просто ехал в одну сторону. Как это делается? Я с анимацией в векторах до этого вообще не работал, а тут понадобилось.

---

```html
<svg width="336px" height="195px">
    <defs>  
  <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="-20%" y1="-20%" x2="120%" y2="120%" gradientTransform="rotate(0)">
 <stop stop-color="black" offset="-10%">
  <animate attributeName="offset" values="-0.20; 0.80" dur="2s" begin="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </stop>
 <stop stop-color="white" offset="-5%">
  <animate attributeName="offset" values="0; 1" dur="2s" begin="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </stop>
 <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%">
  <animate attributeName="offset" values="0.20; 1.20" dur="2s" begin="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </stop>
</linearGradient>
    </defs>
      
    <g>
      <path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" d="M315.69646,6.17948262 C328.855897,-3.88648819 332.169516,-0.795739865 323.113707,13.0582738 L217.327474,174.895153 C208.264469,188.760175 193.218185,188.990964 183.71996,175.409636 L126.769111,93.9767151 L12.5417619,181.728698 C-0.593710633,191.81966 -3.91947426,188.74917 5.1230211,174.855879 L110.403975,13.0975513 C119.44219,-0.789163345 134.468377,-1.03753706 143.966601,12.5437917 L200.917445,93.9767151 L315.69646,6.17948262 Z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Прокачал это дело. Теперь другая проблема, нужно сделать чтобы молния заполнялась полностью белым цветом, и только потом опять становилась черной.

Comment: Проедет он до конца и что дальше?

Comment: @Alex78191 В смысле? Он бесконечно должен ехать.

Comment: у градиента есть начало и конец

Comment: Так увеличьте ширину градиента

Comment: @Alex78191 Я пришел сюда за помощью, а не за советами которые я вероятно попробовал сразу. Вот - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgWmxL?editors=1000#0 Это абсолютно не то что мне нужно. Тут должно быть две анимации сразу: Плавный переход в белый, и потом в черный (https://fex.net/#!065466507306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Градиент должен быть широкий, например, такой, в 3 ширины

Это начальная позиция:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это конечная:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда середина будет такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg width="336px" height="195px">
    <defs>  
  <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="-20%" y1="-20%" x2="120%" y2="120%" gradientTransform="rotate(0)">
 <stop stop-color="black" offset="-10%">
  <animate attributeName="offset" values="-3;  1" dur="4s" begin="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </stop>
 <stop stop-color="white" offset="-5%">
  <animate attributeName="offset" values="-2;  2" dur="4s" begin="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </stop>
 <stop stop-color="white" offset="-5%">
  <animate attributeName="offset" values="-1;  3" dur="4s" begin="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </stop>
 <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%">
  <animate attributeName="offset" values="0; 4" dur="4s" begin="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </stop>
</linearGradient>
    </defs>
      
    <g>
      <path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" d="M315.69646,6.17948262 C328.855897,-3.88648819 332.169516,-0.795739865 323.113707,13.0582738 L217.327474,174.895153 C208.264469,188.760175 193.218185,188.990964 183.71996,175.409636 L126.769111,93.9767151 L12.5417619,181.728698 C-0.593710633,191.81966 -3.91947426,188.74917 5.1230211,174.855879 L110.403975,13.0975513 C119.44219,-0.789163345 134.468377,-1.03753706 143.966601,12.5437917 L200.917445,93.9767151 L315.69646,6.17948262 Z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Идеально, спасибо!